# onComplete div removal

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I'm trying to setup a function to animate out a div on the screen when a link is click. I've setup functions to call divs in and also a function to animate them off when an 'X' button is clicked but I want that function to run when the primary links are clicked and then proceed to animate the new content in. I'm fairly new to jQuery/JavaScript so excuse any ignorance on my part

My current code is as follows -

click function to call div onto screen

```
$("#market a").click(function(){
    $("#market_info").show();
});
```

and function to clear off the divs using the seperate 'X' button

```
$("#fade_bg, .close").click(function(){
    $("#fade_bg").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#infobox").animate({left: '-1200px' }, "slow", function() {
        $("#infobox > div").css("display", "none");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Originally I was going to use an `onComplete` in the links function to run the latter function.

Comment: I think you should post the HTML, and maybe set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), and try to explain even better what the actual problem is, I've read the question three times, and I still don't really get what exactly is not working, other than that it's obviously not working the way you would like it too? Where exactly does `onComplete` fit into this, and how where you going to use that ?

Comment: I have 4 links, when you click a link infobox is animated in, infoBox is a container DIV which holds 4 other DIVs. The links, depending on which you click, will show a second div within that infobox div (you can see the div ID as market_info in the first function). The last function I posted is a function that removes that container infobox div from the screen. My issue is I want to run that function everytime one of the 4 links is clicked so infobox is removed and then added again with the updated content. If this doesn't help I will post the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#infobox").animate({left: '-1200px' }, "slow", function() {
        $(" > div", this).css("display", "none");
    });
```